# Magento Invoice change product name

Tags: product, name

is there any way to create product that you can change name when you are sending invoice? We have some small products that we don't want to create as new products. We use it only when we are doing invoice.

We want to change name and price.

Comment: It is too hard to change product price after order place.It relly bad idea  .LInk http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42452/is-it-possible-to-update-order-item-price-and-order-total-after-order-is-place

Answer (score 1):

Changing prices is no problem, you can set whatever special price you wnat.

But changing the name is no possible out of the box. You can implement a module to do this. But if you ask me, it is a bad idea to print other things on orders than on invoices. So better create the products.