# How can you update prices on previous orders?

Tags: magento-1.9, reports

I put a Magento (1.9.2.4) site live for a week and took around 30 orders, which I can view in reports. Unfortunately, I had to revert to the client's previous site when some issues came up.

I now need to provide the client with accurate sales and profit margin reports for the 7 days I had the site up. The problem is, some of the product pricing (for the wholesale/cost figures) wasn't correct at the time so the reports I produce don't have the correct figures for margin and profit.

Is there any way I can force Magento to use the current (and correct) product pricing rather than some of the incorrect product pricing at the time the transactions went through?

Answer (score 0):

see first [Is it possible to update order item price and order total after order is place](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42452/is-it-possible-to-update-order-item-price-and-order-total-after-order-is-place)

As per as, my thought **price change after order place is not an  identical idea** for an order. bcoz of **depends on lot of  functi**on magento order price is calculated.

If you want to change product price after order place then **it become too ricky**