# Editing Order instead of creating a new Order

Tags: magento-1.9, edit-order

I'm working on a marketplace (multiple sellers). My client has a requirement, where he wants to edit an order and update the items in an order. I tried my best to convince him that instead of editing the order we should follow the magento's existing way, ie cancel and current order and generate a new one. But he dont want to do that. So when while editing an order he wants following features like :

1. Replace an item with a new item (new item may have price
   differences).
2. Remove or cancel and item from the order.
3. Update the Quantity of the item.

I have came across answers like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/61736/35121) where it only updates the price. But in my case i might have to completely replace an item with another item. If i have to replace an item could someone suggest me what are tables that i might need to edit.

I know that its not a recommended way, but i need to do it.

Comment: `sales_flat_order_item` for order   `sales_flat_invoice_item` for invoice  `sales_flat_shipment_item` for shipment

Comment: Keep in mind that when you change the product inside an order, the `grand_total`, `base_grand_total` and other financial values might change as well. That is why Magento cancels the order and creates a new one by default.

Comment: @mizuti Yes and as per my understanding i will have to recalculate all these values since order does not have function like ''CollectTotals' right ?